# MDX - Cumulative Sum Not working when selecting multiple dates

Tags: mdx, cumulative-sum

I've build an MDX calculated member that returns the Cumulative Sales over time.
- the query returns correct results if no filters applied or the user filters with 1 month

**my problem is that when the user selects multiple months the query returns the cumulative for the whole year**

**here is what i wrote using Dynamic Set, Calculated Member and Scope:**

**Dynamic Set:**

PeriodToDate = EXISTING PeriodsToDate([Date].[Calendar - YQMD].[Year],[Date].[Calendar - YQMD].CurrentMember)

**Calculated Member:**

(
    PeriodsToDate([Date].[Calendar - YQMD].[Year],[Date].[Calendar - YQMD].CurrentMember) 
   ,[Measures].[Sales Amount - Foreign] 
)

**Scope:**

Scope 
(
    [Date].[Calendar - YQMD].[Year],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount - Foreign] 
)

This = Aggregate([PeriodToDate],[Measures].[Sales Amount - Foreign])

End Scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Create Dynamic Set CURRENTCUBE.SelectedMonths as [Date].[Calendar - YQMD].[Month].Members;

Scope ( [Date].[Calendar - YQMD].[Year], [Measures].[Sales Amount - Foreign] );
    This = Aggregate(PeriodsToDate([Date].[Calendar - YQMD].[Year], Tail(Existing SelectedMonths,1).Item(0).Item(0)));
End Scope;
```

Comment: Hello Greg. when we moved the solution to production we are facing a problem in executing this MDX on large data. the SSAS does not return data. do you have any advice for this?

Comment: @ZiadMatragi you mean it’s slow or it returns zero rows?

Comment: its extremely slow. we believe it is because of the dynamic set. but we can't find another solution.

Comment: @ZiadMatragi can you test whether your original code is slow or fast? If slow then it’s probably a data size thing. If fast then it’s probably a MDX thing. The optimization is different for each

Comment: when we ran it on a data of size 100 MB it was extremely fast. but then became extremly slow when moved to a 3GB data

Comment: your code. runs fast on 100MB and slow on 3GB. to be exact the dynamic set. any thoughts that might help?

Comment: @ZiadMatragi please test your code on large data sizes and report back

Comment: hello Greg, my code is the same as yours i just changed the measures. would you like me send it here?

Comment: @ZiadMatragi right. Test your original measures from your question. That performance should indicate the problem